# Manually destroy component

Tags: angular, angular5

My application has tab controls that use a `router-outlet` to display the content for each tab. Because the user can close a tab at any point, I need a way to programmatically get the component associated with that tab and have Angular destroy it.

Normally, this would be done via the `detach()` method in route reuse strategy, but because of the tab control, I'm using a custom route reuse strategy and the detach method can't help once its time to actually destroy the component.

I've tried to access the `<router-outlet>` as a `ViewChild` to get at the `component` property, but it always appears to be `undefined`.

Long story-short, is there a way to get a list of components from the `router-outlet` that have not been destroyed and destroy them on demand?

Comment: angular isn't automatically calling ngOnDestroy when a tab is closed?

Comment: @pixelbits No. How would it know to? My custom routing strategy tells it not to via returning true from `detatch` (because the tab might be selected again later). Only when the tab close button is actually clicked does it need to dispose of the component (which may not be on screen at the moment)